# How to map the Server.MapPath to a directory on a local machine or a server?

Tags: c#, solaris, server.mappath

I program in C# that uploads the file contents to a directory within the website folder.The **Server.MapPath** method stores the file to the folder Upload which is a part of the website. If there is a server can I upload the files there by giving the IP and the location such as **"137.2.42.244/Documents"**. The server OS is a Solaris.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace FileUpLoadMVC.Controllers
{
    public class FileUploadController : Controller
    {
        // GET: FileUpload
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public void UploadFiles()
        {
            if (Request.Files?.Count > 0)
            {
                var filesCount = Request.Files.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < filesCount; i++)
                {
                    var file = Request.Files[i];
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Upload"), fileName);

                    file.SaveAs(path);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: var path = Path.Combine(("C:/users/Desktop/ "), fileName); stores it to local directory but still researching about Solaris.

Comment: You need to provide some more information.  Are you running this C# code on a Windows computer?  Do you know how the Solaris server is sharing out the filesystem?  Is it using Samba?  ZFS CIFS share?  Something else?

Comment: @Andrew Henle C# code is on Windows Computer. I am very new to Solaris so no clue about the sharing. It's a Solaris 5.10.

Comment: If you bring up Windows Explorer and go to "Network", can you see the Solaris server? If so, the Solaris server is likely sharing the filesystem via a Windows protocol, so you should be able to map the drive just like if it was on a Windows server.  See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323386/how-to-connect-to-shared-folders-over-the-network-on-a-domain-in-windo  Even if you don't see the Solaris server, you probably still can map the drive to your local Windows computer the same way.